# What does the color window radius in pyrMeanShiftFiltering mean?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, colors, rgb, mean-shift

My understanding of a RGB color vector is that it has 3 components like [100, 100, 100]. However, [from the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#pyrmeanshiftfiltering), the argument `sr – The color window radius` in the Python function `cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(src, sp, sr[, dst[, maxLevel[, termcrit]]])` accepts an int.

What exactly does color radius mean? I'd also like to understand the min and max values, and what the units are in.

Comment: did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I read in the description of the algorithm from the documentation, `sr` is a parameter for a part of the algorithm which needs neighbor identification.

You might want to brush over your understanding of the mean shift algorithm, but at some point for a given pixel (X,Y), you need to find its neighbors. While often, we think as neighbors as *spatial* neighbors, i.e. pixels close spatially to the one we're considering ( ||(X,Y)-(x,y)||< some radius, with X,Y the considered pixel position and x,y the potential neighbor position), here the algorithm also considers the "color" closeness, as seen in the line :

> the pixel (X,Y) neighborhood in the joint space-color hyperspace is
>   considered:
>
> (x,y): X- sp < x < X + sp , Y- sp < y < Y+ sp, ||(R,G,B)-(r,g,b)|| <
>   sr

This means to be considered a neighbor, a pixel needs to be spatially close and have also a close color to the considered pixel. You set this closeness condition with `sr`, just like you set required spatial closeness with `sp`. Try some values out. It depends on what definition the algorithm uses for the || norm, probably something like ||(R,G,B)-(r,g,b)|| = sqrt((R-r)**2+(G-g)**2+(B-b)**2)

Comment: Do you know of a way to find out if color distance is sqrt((R-r)**2+(G-g)**2+(B-b)**2)?

Comment: Try it out with test pixels you know the value of ? ;)
Other than that, I can't really imagine it being something else than this norm. ||x|| can mean a variety of things, but Wikipedia calls the euclidian distance (the norm we're discussing) "by far the most commonly used norm on R^n"